# network management application

Tags: c#, .net

I am supposed to write an application to manage all devices connected to a network e.g routers, radios, etc, I've figured a way to know the devices connected, but my challenge right now is how to figure out the bandwidth consumed by each interface of these devices on the network.

Comment: ...and the question is.... hard to determine. Could you give us a little more detail, and a well-formed question?

Comment: And how do you find all the devices in the network? SNMP?

Comment: i want to determine bandwith used by devices on the network

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to use SNMP to gather the data. If SNMP isn't supported by the particular devices you're using, you may have other options that are more specific to each device.

Comment: please how do i know the oid<bandwidth> for a particular device

Comment: You'll have to look in the device's documentation for how to retrieve that particular piece of information through SNMP (if it's possible...)